# Converting webpage to PDF preserving latex

Tags: google-chrome, internet, pdf, printing, webpage

I tried many of the converters but none of them preserve the content in latex. For eg:- http://www.campusgate.co.in/2015/03/numbers-basics.html. Here the latex part is not converted properly.

Is there any way to convert it ? I want only the problems in a PDF format so that I could print it.

Comment: What do you mean and doesn't preserve what content exactly? Show same data and expected sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try google chrome built in PDF converter.

1) Ctrl + P (print)
2) Click on change button.
3) Select Save as PDF.
4) Click Save. You will get the webpage as PDF.

Comment: It omits content many times.

Answer (score 3):

Harikrishnan's answer works great. If you have multiple pages to convert in one go, or need APIs to convert from code **Sejda PDF** works great for that.

## Sejda PDF

[Sejda PDF](https://www.sejda.com/) can [convert HTML pages to PDF](https://www.sejda.com/html-to-pdf).

The online service can be used for free for up to 3 conversions per hour. A [HTML to PDF API](https://www.sejda.com/developers#api-html-to-pdf) is also available.

### Usage

- Open https://www.sejda.com/html-to-pdf
- Paste the URLs
- Click on **Convert HTML to PDF**

[image: Convert HTML to PDF in your browser using Sejda PDF]

### Example

Click to convert direct link:

https://www.sejda.com/html-to-pdf?save-link=http://www.campusgate.co.in/2015/03/numbers-basics.html

The resulting PDF:

[image]

Disclaimer: I help building this tool.